# Asynchronous synchronization Sql Server CE 4.0 to centralized Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, sql-server-ce, replication, sql-server-ce-4

If Sql Server CE 4.0 is being used as an edge cache for a distributed web application, how would one asynchronously synchronize the data back to a centralized database for reporting purposes?

Secondly, would this be possible inside of shared hosting such that custom service applications/exectuables  are not reasonably available?

I'm looking for actual guidance, if your answer would be "Use the Microsoft Sync framework" or along those lines please include atleast a rough explanation of how exactly I would want to do that in a way that it makes the most sense. Optimally this would occur automatically, through some form of scheduling instead of requiring a push the button approach. If this is readily only available through push the button approach I imagine I can accomplish that through some form of restful call to "push the button".

Comment: If you are using SQL CE as a cache (read-only), what data would you want to sync back ??

Comment: I never said it was a read only database, it's to store high frequency information such as site usage data near line in a distributed system. This is to alleviate the load of all of the distributed nodes trying to write to the centralize database concurrently and instead replicate the data to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a central program (service or scheduled task) to pull (file copy(download) the sdf files form the web servers (could be via a web service exposed on each web server) and consolidate on the central DB server. Not sure what you would do with "old" data on the web servers, it depends... The same web service on each server could also take care of that.

Comment: Well that certainly *could* be an option, but this seems like it would be the absolute sledgehammer approach if every other option fails for some reason. Also I'd have concerns about even being able to reliably copy the file as it would be in use.

Comment: I still extremely dislike this answer, but you deserve the bounty for atleast saying *anything* on here.